# Jquery maximum 3 validation for textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, validation

I am trying to validate textfield for my form to not allow more than 3 integer value.

```html
<div class="form-group col-lg-5">
  {!! Form::label('qty', 'TradedQuantity:') !!} 
  {!! Form::text('qty', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    qty: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 3
    }
  });
});
```

I don't know what i am missing here.

I have done but, till not working : `maxlength: 3`

[image]

Comment: Why not just use `maxlength="3"`?

Comment: lol, it was mistake in Question Content... I have edited it. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: No I mean use the HTML `maxlength` attribute. Then there's no need to validate the length in JS.

Comment: Oh! You are right but, I asked question herein because, When i use the HMTL `maxlength` : 3, it will message after submitting form. I want to warning to user while filling form. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: If you do want to use jQuery validate for this then the correct rule name is `maxlength`, not `max`: https://jqueryvalidation.org/maxlength-method/

Comment: Ok I ll, but it will not give message to user like "your value should less than 4" @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: You're not understanding what I'm saying. I added an answer below to give you the full code. Hopefully now it makes more sense.

Comment: Yes I understood therefore, i have `thumb up` and i have done `maxlength: 3` but i want to print the message user also if user break validation. @RoryMcCrossan.

Comment: You need to add the messages in the `rules` object. I updated the answer below to give you the full thing in a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because jQuery validate() has no `max` rule. If you want to restrict the number of characters which can be entered, the correct rule name is [`maxlength`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/maxlength-method/). Also note that validation rules need to be placed in the `rules` object. I'd strongly suggest you read the plugin's [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/).

```js
$('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    qty: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 3
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-5">
    <label>
      Traded Quantity
      <input type="text" name="qty" class="form-control" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note that you could instead use the `maxlength` HTML attribute on the `input` directly.

Comment: i have also posted screen of my `textfield`.

Comment: I updated the answer for you. You're missing the `rules` property.

Comment: jquery validation pass through only id? not Name, ID, and label of class, this is possible  ?? -@Rory McCrossan

Comment: No, it uses the `name` attribute only, as all `input` elements should have a `name`

Comment: when i change label class and id this is doesn't effect working in validation??? <label for="quality">Traded Quantity</label>
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="quality" class="form-control" />  -@Rory McCrossan

Comment: It shouldn't. If you're having issues with it, I'd suggest starting a new question

Comment: when i use only name in jquery validation, it doesn't work for me -@Rory McCrossan

Comment: <div class="form-group col-lg-5">
                {!! Form::label('rate', 'Traded Rate:') !!}
                {!! Form::text('rate', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
            </div>

Comment: There must be some other underlying issue with your code. I edited the answer above to use the `name` attribute only and you can see that it works fine